# AverageIf Moving Average

Tags: excel, excel-formula, moving-average

I'm trying to find a 5yr Moving Average that takes a condition of the month of the year. Column A contains daily dates from 1/1/2010 all the way to today's current date. Column B contains a daily quantity. Basically I want to average all the days for January in a rolling 5 year period. I could easily do this as a static number, but this sheet will be updated daily.

Ex:

```
Date        Quantity
1/1/2010    14,113
1/2/2010    15,364
```

etc...

I've written this formula:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(OFFSET(B2,COUNT(B2:B10000)-1826,0,1826,1),A2:A10000,MONTH(A2:A10000)=1)
```

This returns `#VALUE!`

Comment: if `COUNT(B2:B10000)` is less than 1825 then it will try to offset to a cell that does not exist.

Comment: Also you can't do `MONTH(A2:A10000)=1` like that in AVERAGEIFS()

Comment: There are currently 2,800 rows

Comment: Have you considered setting up as table and adding it to a data model. You could then use DAX to write something that would perform this calculation. There are some pre-requisites. See the following: https:community.powerbi.com/t5/desktop/Moving-average/td-p/43041

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to use AVERAGEIFS().  The AVERAGEIFS only do simple iteration, no conversion.

I prefer to use INDEX to get the range since it is not Volatile, when setting variable ranges.

Also all the ranges must be the same size. So limiting Column B to 1826 cells but not limiting Column A to the same 1826 cells will cause a second error.

Use this array formula:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(MONTH(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,B:B)-1826):INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,B:B)))=1,INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1E+99,B:B)-1826):INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1E+99,B:B))))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

---

You can also use the dates themselves instead of a hard coded 1826 days.  This will allow for leap year.

```
=AVERAGE(IF(MONTH(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(DATE(YEAR(TODAY())-5,MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY())),A:A,0)):INDEX(A:A,MATCH(TODAY(),A:A)))=1,INDEX(B:B,MATCH(DATE(YEAR(TODAY())-5,MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY())),A:A,0)):INDEX(B:B,MATCH(TODAY(),A:A))))
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you for doing this so quickly. I've use Index only a handful of times, so this has me wanting to brush up a bit more. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option

`=AVERAGE(IF(A2:A5000>EDATE(TODAY(),-60),IF(MONTH(A2:A5000)=1,B2:B5000)))`

confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

This doesn't try to find a specific range of data, just looks at all the data and averages rows where the date is in the last 5 years and also in January. There's some extra overhead looking at all rows but you have a relatively small amount of data so I wouldn't expect that to be significant

Comment: If you have not notice I tend to be more complicated than I need sometimes.  This is a better answer.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've had to adjust this project a bit and using this formula made it a little easier to make some quick changes.